# issue in object selection in fabricjs when outer div is scaled

Tags: css, canvas, transformation, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs to add text and images to canvas.All my canvases are added in a single div.When i scale the div using css3 transformation, i get my canvases scaled with the items added in the canvases also scaled to the same proportion.

The problem occurs when i wish to select any of the object. The handler position remains the same.Below is the code snippet.

```
<div id="designUI" ng-style="transform:scale(2,2)">
    <div>
        <canvas width="100" height="100">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't scale your canvas with CSS, use the `width` and `height` properties.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you manage to solve it? it would be much better performance wise to be able to use the css transform rather than scaling each object inside the canvas.

Comment: Don't scale your canvas with CSS, use the width and height properties.